# Nuxt3 Child routes and active class in navigation

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have a navigation - One of the link is linking to "/users" (Nuxt3 project)

When I'm on the "/users" route, I have a subnavigation linking to "/users/groups"

But when I land on the route "/users/groups" - I don't get the active class in the main navigation on the "/users", even though "/users/groups" is a child route?

My structure looks like this:

[image]

The layout both /users/index.vue and /users/groups/index.vue uses outputs `<NuxtPage :page-key="$route.path" />`

Do I need to structure it differently to get my main navigation to see that "/users/groups" are a child of "/users" and then add the active class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure is correct. You just need to create a `users.vue` file inside the pages with the `NuxtPage` content.

`~/pages/users.vue`

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <NuxtPage />
    </div>
</template>
```

I created an example for you and it is working. See screenshot
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-w48c5q?file=pages/users/index.vue
[image]

Hope that helps you