# Nuxt3: Dynamic child routes dont trigger active-class

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Active class only applies to main route, but not to child routes

Child routes is dynamic and optional

**This is my pages directory**

[image: pages directory]

[image: active view]

[image: not active view]

**NavBar.vue**

```js
<nav>
        <ul class="flex flex-wrap space-x-5 py-4 text-sm text-slate-600">
          <li>
            <NuxtLink
              active-class="text-slate-700 font-medium"
              to="/feed"
              class="leading-none tracking-wide hover:underline hover:underline-offset-2"
              >Ana səhifə
            </NuxtLink>
          </li>
          <li>|</li>
          <li v-for="route in routes" :key="route.name">
            <NuxtLink
              active-class="text-slate-700 font-medium"
              :to="`/flows/${route.slug}`"
              class="leading-none tracking-wide hover:underline hover:underline-offset-2"
              >{{ route.name }}
            </NuxtLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

**app.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div class="min-h-screen bg-slate-100">
    <BlogHeader />

    <NavBar :routes="routes" />
    <div class="mx-auto mt-5 grid max-w-6xl grid-cols-12 space-x-3 px-5 pb-10">
      <div class="col-span-8"><NuxtPage /></div>
      <div class="col-span-4 w-full bg-white px-3 py-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Try use `exact-active-class` on `NuxtLink` component

Comment: I've already tried, actually, there is a similar question, but it didn't help me
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76217654/nuxt3-child-routes-and-active-class-in-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the directory structure first. You need to have a `.vue` file with the **same name** as the directory at the **same directory level**. And you need to include `<NuxtPage />` in that .vue file. Only then will it truly meet the nested directory structure required by `<NuxtLink/>`.

```
- pages
  - index.vue
  - folder1/
    - index.vue
    - folder2/
      - index.vue
    - folder2.vue //same level with /folder2 !!!
  - folder1.vue //same level with /folder1 !!!
```

In `folder1.vue` & `folder2.vue`:

```
<template>
    <NuxtPage />
</template>
```